# Хранение имени БД в переменной

Tags: sql-server, integration-services

В поле SQLStatement нужно выполнить запрос для определенной таблицы. Например
DELETE FROM TableName - где и как нужно объявить переменную и как правильно вписать ее в SQLStatement?
Пробовал через 'DELETE FROM ?' - в вопрос передавалось имя таблицы из $Package переменной string типа - не работало.

Comment: Динамический SQL. Собираете текст запроса в переменной и выполняете через EXEC.

Comment: С ним получается почти то же самое по объему, от чего я стараюсь уйти, ладно, видимо так нельзя сделать.